# Create animated tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I would like to create a table that is animated in this style:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/iq85pgaj2getbro/Untitled.mov?dl=0

As you can see in the video the cells are animated exactly to cover the entire screen after they are being dragged.

How can this be implemented?

Answer (score 1):

On a scroll view, simply set `pagingEnabled` to true. The scroll view will always round up or down the scroll offset so that it ends up on a multiple of the scroll view's bounds.

As an `UITableView` inherits from `UIScrollView`, it may be possible to set it on a tableview as well, not sure if the table view code has anything that would conflict.

One thing you may need to look out for, though, are insets for the parts underneath the top and bottom bars.

Another option is simply to implement one of the scroll view delegate methods, such as `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:` ou `scrollViewDidEndDragging: willDecelerate:` to do the rounding yourself. The exact method to implement depends on the exact behaviour you want to get.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to use UIPageViewController with vertical swipe.